# Piecewise polynomial interpolation basis

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Assume the vector space : $S^{0,1}([a,b]) = \{s \in C^0 {([a,b])} : s_{|I_i} \in P_1(I_i), i=0..n \}$ assume we have a a continuous function f defined over [a,b] and we extract $a=x_0,..., x_n=b$. My problem is to prove that this function when taken as a set ${H_k}$ forms a basis for that vector space [This is my function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWyBg.png)